# How can I search and parse multiple, session-specific search results with Scrapy?

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy

[EDIT: Code is revised to show my attempt at doing Granitosaurus' suggestion]

I need to execute some predefined searches and crawl the results 1 level deep, then parse those pages. This has to be done sequentially because the site will not allow results to be crawled unless those results were just retrieved pursuant to a search.

My predefined searches are in a list and I'm trying to loop through that list, but I cannot get it to work. Scrapy either jumps all around or loops through all the start_requests without parsing each as it goes. Can anyone show me a way to do this? Thanks!

The search terms are simply pairs of date ranges which I've stored in a list at the beginning.

Here's my [NEWLY EDITED] code with my non-working loop commented out:

```
import scrapy


monthlist = [{'from_date': '9/1/13', 'to_date': '9/30/13'},
    {'from_date': '10/1/13', 'to_date': '10/31/13'},
    {'from_date': '11/1/13', 'to_date': '11/30/13'},
    {'from_date': '12/1/13', 'to_date': '12/31/13'},
    {'from_date': '1/1/14', 'to_date': '1/31/14'},
    {'from_date': '2/1/14', 'to_date': '2/28/14'},
    {'from_date': '3/1/14', 'to_date': '3/31/14'},
    {'from_date': '4/1/14', 'to_date': '4/30/14'},
    {'from_date': '5/1/14', 'to_date': '5/31/14'},
    {'from_date': '6/1/14', 'to_date': '6/30/14'},
    {'from_date': '7/1/14', 'to_date': '7/31/14'},
    {'from_date': '8/1/14', 'to_date': '8/31/14'},
    {'from_date': '9/1/14', 'to_date': '9/30/14'}]
    # remainder of list snipped for this post


class docketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'robey'
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1,
        'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue',
        'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
    }
    start_urls = ['http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/default.aspx']
    monkeycount = 0
    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(33):
            self.monkeycount =+ 1
            yield scrapy.Request('http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/default.aspx', dont_filter=True)
            yield scrapy.Request('http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/default.aspx', self.parse, dont_filter=True)
        # yield scrapy.Request('http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/Search.aspx?ID=200&NodeID=1256&NodeDesc=393rd%20Judicial%20District%20Court', dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        request = scrapy.Request('http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/Search.aspx?ID=200&NodeID=1256&NodeDesc=393rd%20Judicial%20District%20Court',
            callback=self.retrieve_caselist)
        return request

    def retrieve_caselist(self, response):
        # caserange = {'from_date': '9/1/2013', 'to_date': '9/30/2013'}
        # for caserange in monthlist:
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            url='http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/Search.aspx?ID=200&NodeID=1256&NodeDesc=393rd%20Judicial%20District%20Court',
            formdata={'CaseSearchMode': 'CaseNumber', 'SearchBy': '6', 'ExactName': 'on', 'PartySearchMode': 'Name', 'AttorneySearchMode': 'Name', 'cboState': 'AA', 'CaseStatusType': '0', 'SortBy': 'fileddate', 'SearchSubmit': 'Search', 'SearchType': 'CASE', 'StatusType': 'true', 'AllStatusTypes': 'true', 'SearchParams': 'DateFiled~~Search By:~~6~~Date Filed||chkExactName~~Exact Name:~~on~~on||AllOption~~Case Status:~~0~~All||DateFiledOnAfter~~Date Filed On or After:~~' + monthlist[self.monkeycount]['from_date'] + '~~' + monthlist[self.monkeycount]['from_date'] + '||DateFiledOnBefore~~Date Filed On or Before:~~' + monthlist[self.monkeycount]['to_date'] + '~~' + monthlist[self.monkeycount]['to_date'] + '||selectSortBy~~Sort By:~~Filed Date~~Filed Date', 'SearchMode': 'FILED', 'DateFiledOnAfter': monthlist[self.monkeycount]['from_date'], 'DateFiledOnBefore': monthlist[self.monkeycount]['to_date']},
            callback=self.parse_caselist,
            dont_filter=True
        )

    def parse_caselist(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//html/body/table/tr/td/a/@href').extract():
            full_url = response.urljoin(href)
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_casedetail)


    def parse_casedetail(self, response):
        yield {
            'case_num': response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/span/text()').extract(),
            'attorneys': response.xpath('/html/body/table[4]/tr/td/b/text()').extract(),
            'file_date': response.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tr/td[3]/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td/b/text()').extract(),
            'case_type': response.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tr/td[3]/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td/b/text()').extract()
        }
```

When this runs, it loops through the loop making each request, but it fails to call self.parse on each loop (along with all the callables that run in turn, after self.parse). After the loop, it parses a single set of search results, then acts like it's finished. Here's the [pastebin log of it running](http://pastebin.com/embed/7Bn0DM3U) from PyCharm. Any ideas?

Comment: The first visit to http://justice1.dentoncounty.com/PublicAccessDC/default.aspx starts a session and prompts a redirect to the exact same URL, that's why it's listed twice. Being a .ASP site, with weird session rules, I need to retrieve the exact form and only modify what's needed when posting my request--otherwise I could just send a series of post requests from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are being restricted by the website session. What you could try is to spawn multiple sessions in `start_requests()` and then for each session yield unique search query.

Something like:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_url = "http://scrapy.org"
    search_options = [
        {'name': 'john', 'last_name': 'snow'},
        {'name': 'james', 'last_name': 'bond'},
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        # Start a web session for every search option
        for i, option in enumerate(self.search_options):
            yield Request(self.start_url,
                          dont_filter=True,
                          meta={'search_option': option,
                                'cookiejar': i})

    def parse(self, response):
        # make search request with those specific options!
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, 
                                        callback=self.parse_search,
                                        meta=response.meta,
                                        formdata=response['search_option'])

    def parse_search(self, response):
        # parse your search here
```

Comment: Hey, Granitosaurus. Thanks for your response! I will totally try that out. It's probably faster than doing everything sequentially anyway.

Comment: It did not work... For this I would need each post request and subsequent parsing to be tied to the same session. As in, each session needs to: post the search request, send response to parser, visit all linked pages in response, parse those pages.

Comment: Is there a way to post a request within the start_requests method and while still in that method take the response and post another request from that response?

Comment: @evan I don't understand why it didn't work for you but regarding your second question, there is something called [scrapy inline requests](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-inline-requests) which allows you to schedule/retrieve requests inside of your methods.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds perfect! Also, to explain what happened when I tried your approach of putting the loop in start_requests: Scrapy ran through the entire loop of requests first, then parsed only the first request and ended. Obviously, I need it to do the first request, follow links, parse results, then the second request, etc.

Comment: I'm so frustrated at this point I think I'm going to switch to using the requests module by itself. (and BeautifulSoup for parsing) But now I can't seem to reuse a session properly for the way this site deals with forms...

Comment: Just edited the code in my post to show my attempt at your suggestion. I've included the log, too. Thoughts?

Comment: @evan Why is your code using `for in range` and yieldtding two requests? Another suggestion would be use a cookiejar to store sessions, see my edit (`meta` part in the `start_requests()` method).

Comment: Assuming that start_requests uses an empty session each time, I have to hit that url first to initiate a session, then visit it again to actually pick something and submit it. I've hit that url before after a wait, manually in my browser, picked something in the dropdown and clicked the link (it's a link instead of submit on the first part) and all it would do is refresh the page, starting a new session. It's a weird site. So for crawling I just make sure to hit it twice.

Comment: @evan if you want to "hit something twice" you need to chain it appropriatly, one by one, because of asynchronious nature of scrapy. Here's an example I wrote on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw/FNcLdcMb